# Angular httpclient 4.3 rewrite response status from 200 to 500

Tags: httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have a server that responds with 200 status always but responds with errorCode in the body. I want to intercept that response and rewrite the status to 403 or 500. How do i do this with the new http interceptors? here is code thus far

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req)
      .map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse  && (event.body.errorCode)) {
          return event.clone({status: 500})
        }  
      });
   }
}
```